# Are There Any Good C++ Suffix Trie Libraries?

Tags: c++, algorithm, tree, nlp, trie

Does anyone know of a really rock solid C++ library for suffix tries?  Other than the one in Mummer?
Ideally, I'd like:
Some concept of concurrency.
Good caching behavior.
Permissive license.
Support for arbitrary alphabets.

Comment: Looks like someone proposed a boost GSoC project for one - http://lists.boost.org/Archives/boost/2009/04/150393.php can't find any results from it yet though.

Comment: Seems there is at least one promising library already actually from the follow up to that: http://code.google.com/p/patl/

Comment: @awoodland: great link, I especially like the Levenshtein iterator with support for optional operations.

Comment: Patl is really solid, I forgot it had suffix tries.  Would you like to make that an answer?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Being a bioinformatician, my pick would be [SeqAn](http://www.seqan.de/) (check out the [sequence index](http://trac.mi.fu-berlin.de/seqan/wiki/Tutorial/Indices) section). It implements a lazy suffix tree and an enhanced suffix array (an equivalent data structure), both of which have good cache behaviour.

Comment: Ooh! One I hadn't heard of, and with a suffix array too!  That's fantastic.

Comment: Upvote. I like the gloabal functionality of this library. I have just started exploring it. Something that should be mentioned IMO is that, for some tasks, it may be not fast enough. Personal preliminary comparisons show that, e.g. by using a seqan::Alphabet, things can get slowed down significantly, even when using e.g. Array-Alloc for Strings. (compared to using a std::vector of std::string as alphabet). Probably the traditional comfort vs. speed situation.

Answer (score 2):

Having actually used and then forgotten PATL, I'd like to tuck in a link in an answer.
http://code.google.com/p/patl/
It's got a couple really distinct features, and is generally pleasant reading as well.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely this is a tutorial but IMO worth reading and with source code: http://marknelson.us/1996/08/01/suffix-trees.